# DartEditor and SDK version 1.9.0-dev.3.0 do not display error hints in .html links

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am using DartEditor and SDK version is 1.9.0-dev.3.0 as Dart eclipse plugin.

The current versions do not display warning or error hints with incorrect links in the .html files.

Consider the following

```dart
<link rel='import' href='../../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html' >
<link rel='import' href='packages/html_components/input/select_item.html'>
```

The first link is correct, the second is not. However, there is no hints or warnings displayed on the page. This only occurred after I updated to the current version from the previous DEV version of Dart.

However, when I run the dart application is Dartium, the error is displayed to the console. It seems as if something is broken in Dart SDK 1.9.0-dev3.0.

Thanks

Comment: What Polymer version are you using? This shouldn't depend on the SDK version, only on Polymer.

Comment: I suggest creating a bug report, maybe a regression.